# PartialView with model in View with out model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hello is it possible to run PartialView with model inside View without model, or I have to create model which will contains models for partial views?
Example:

```
User have his site:
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyPanel";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
        <!--Right Menu-->
        <div id="RightMenu" class="col-md-10" style="max-height:550px; overflow-y:scroll;">
            @Html.Action("AllSongs","UserPanel")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to Render PartialView AllSongs which contains model.

```
public PartialViewResult AllSongs() {
        var userId = (int)Session["Login"];
        var songs = context.Songs.Where(x => x.UserID.Equals(userId));
        return PartialView(songs);
    }
```

But when code go inside this method I got error like this:

```
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, however that action is going to load different that what you are expecting. I think you would want that to load outside of what else is going on. If that is the case you could return the content of that partial and place it in an element --> `$('#MyDiv').html('@Model.AllSongsHtmlContnet');` You can use a helper function in your controller to return something like:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no another way to do this, by Html.RednerAction or RenderPartial or sth like that?

Comment: RenderPartial returns the whole blob and replaces the dom. I think you have to do this piecemeal. Think of a base controller class that has a Html content and a base model that can return a string that is html.